# how to unhide the app bar and bottom navigation bar while navigating from side menu drawer using flutter?

Tags: flutter

I am creating a new app with a bottom navigation bar and app bar on top. I have the side menu drawer listing some menus. The problem is if I click any menu in the menu drawer it is navigating to the page but both the bottom navigation bar and app bar are hiding and the page takes the full screen. Kindly help to resolve this.

```
class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget{
     final int indexvalue;
      HomeScreen({Key key, @required this.indexvalue}) : super(key: key);
      @override
      State createState() {
        return HomeScreenState();
      }
    }

    class HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
      final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _scaffoldKey = new GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
      int _selectedPage = 0;
      final _pageOptions = [
       Screen1(),
       WebView1(),
       Home(),
       Leader(),
        // Menu(),
      ];

     Future<List<User>> _getUsers() async{
       var data = await http.get("https://api");
       var jsonData = json.decode(data.body);
       var jsonData1 = jsonData['menu'];
       List<User> users = [];
       for(var u in jsonData1){
         User user = User(u["Id"], u["Menu_Name"], u["Menu_Icon"], u["Deep_Link_Name"]);
         users.add(user);
       }
       print(users.length);
       return users;
     }

      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context){
        Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
        var val = widget.indexvalue;
        print(widget.indexvalue);
        return MaterialApp(
          title: 'Home',
          home: Scaffold(
            key: _scaffoldKey,
            appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Home'),),
            body: _pageOptions[_selectedPage],
             endDrawer:  SizedBox(
               //width: size.width,
               child: Drawer(
                 elevation: 1.5,
              child: new ListView(
                children: <Widget>[
                  new DrawerHeader(
                    child: new Text("Drawer Header"),
                    decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.blue,
                    ),
                  ),

                    Container(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10.0),
                    height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height-150.0,
                    child:FutureBuilder(
                            future: _getUsers(),
                            builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot){
                              if(snapshot.data == null){
                                return Container(
                                  child:Center(child: Text("....Loading....."))
                                );
                              } else {
                                return Scrollbar(
                                  child:ListView.builder(
                                  //shrinkWrap: true,
                                itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index){
                                   var aa = int.parse(snapshot.data[index].Menu_Icon);
                                   var deepLinkName = snapshot.data[index].Deep_Link_Name;
                                   print(deepLinkName);
                                  return ListTile(
                                    dense: true,
                                    onTap: () { print('tapped');
                                    },
                                    title: Text('${snapshot.data[index].Menu_Name}'),
                                    leading: new Icon(IconData(aa, fontFamily: 'faRegular'), size: 25.0, color: Colors.blueAccent),
                                  );
                                }
                                )
                                );
                              }

                            }
                          )
                  )

                ],
              ),
            ),
             ),
            bottomNavigationBar: new Theme(
              data: Theme.of(context).copyWith(
                  // sets the background color of the `BottomNavigationBar`
                  canvasColor: Colors.green,
                  // sets the active color of the `BottomNavigationBar` if `Brightness` is light
                  primaryColor: Colors.red,
                  textTheme: Theme
                      .of(context)
                      .textTheme
                      .copyWith(caption: new TextStyle(color: Colors.yellow))), // sets the inactive color of the `BottomNavigationBar`
              child: new BottomNavigationBar(
                showSelectedLabels: false,   // <-- HERE
                showUnselectedLabels: false,
              currentIndex: _selectedPage,
              onTap: (int index) {
                setState(() {
                  _selectedPage = index;
                });
              },
              items: [
                BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.home), title: Text('Home')),
                BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.photo_library), title: Text('photo_library')),
                BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.book), title: Text('book')),
                BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.notifications), title: Text('download')),
              ],

              ),
            ),
          )
        );
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your description and your code, you should be using a `PageView` widget instead of creating your own. Take a look at the Widget in the documentation: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/PageView-class.html

You can still user your `BottomNavigationBar` to control the pages.